# How to create/use a DependencyProperty that generates its value when read?

Tags: wpf, generator, dependency-properties

I would like to create a [`DependencyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) that generates a value each time it is read; e.g. something like:

```
private static Random _rng = new Random();

public int RandomNumber
{
    get
    {
        int x = _rng.Next();
        SetValue(RandomNumberProperty, x);
        return x;
    }
}
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey RandomNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(RandomNumber), typeof(int), typeof(Window1), new PropertyMetadata(-1));
```

And use this property to fill a [CommandParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandparameter(v=vs.110).aspx); e.g.:

```
public static RoutedUICommand CmdRandomNumber = new RoutedUICommand() { Text = "Use a random number supplied as parameter." };

private void ExecuteShowMessage(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"And the winner is ... {(int)e.Parameter}" );
}

private void CanExecuteShowMessage(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Window1.CmdRandomNumber}"
                        Executed="ExecuteShowMessage"
                        CanExecute="CanExecuteShowMessage" />
        </CommandBinding>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Button Command="{x:Static local:Window1:CmdRandomNumber}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding RandomNumber}"/>
</Window>
```

However, this does not work: `ExecuteShowMessage` always receives the initial value.  Probably since the [`DependencyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) is not notified about the value change and when the value of the `DependencyProperty` is requested, it returns its cached value instead of retrieving it from `RandomNumber`.

*I would like to bind different parameters to different buttons and have each execute the same command; therefore I tried using the [`CommandParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of reading `RandomValue` from within `ExecuteShowMessage`.*

How to implement a property that can be used in WPF databindings that generates its value each time it is read?  And how to ensure that its backing proerty is read instead of the [`DependencyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) relying on its cached value?  (Especially in the context of [`CommandParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).)

Comment: A dependency property is not supposed to work that way. Its CLR wrapper must not call anything else than GetValue and SetValue in the get and set accessor. However, if the property serves as the source of a Binding, it doesn't need to be dependency property.

Comment: You can't ensure that the CLR wrapper is always used to retrieve the value of the dependency property. And the GetValue and SetValue methods are not virtual so you cannot override them. Whatever you are trying to do, you should consider another approach.

Comment: That last argument to the DP --  `new PropertyMetadata(-1)` is the default. If you can figure out a way to return a pre-created static random value instead of -1, you might succeed in that approach.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling thanks for the suggestion, but I want the random value to change every time the command is executed; a random initial value is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to implement a property that can be used in WPF databindings that
>   generates its value each time it is read?

The source property of a WPF Binding can be an ordinary CLR property, like this:

```
public int RandomNumber
{
    get { return _rng.Next(); }
}
```

In case you need to force a Binding to be updated to read a new property value, the class that owns the property may implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and fire the `PropertyChanged` event whenever necessary, like:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RandomNumber"));
```